# IOS - Call function in Modal View from parent

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling with calling a function in a modal view from parent screen.

I've set up a function in my modal view . m file as follows -

```
-(void)setGoal:(NSString*)setGoal
{
 _bals = setGoal;
 NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _setType];

_display.text = result;
}
```

I'm trying to trigger this function from the parent view via the following -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  editGoalViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goalInfo"])
  {

    [segue.destinationViewController setYourGoalViewController:self];
     [segue.destinationViewController setGoal:100];

  }
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"longGoalInfo"])
  {
    [segue.destinationViewController setYourGoalViewController:self];
    [segue.destinationViewController setGoal:100];
  }
}
```

But I get an error stating 'no known instance method for selector setGoal'- which I dont understand!  Any tips welcome!

Screenshot -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call the method because the compiler doesn't recognize your destinationViewController as the same class of your intended UIViewController.

Replace evey call of `segue.destinationViewController` to `destViewController`.
So you code will be

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  editGoalViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goalInfo"])
  {

    [destViewController setYourGoalViewController:self];
     [destViewController setGoal:100];

  }
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"longGoalInfo"])
  {
    [destViewController setYourGoalViewController:self];
    [destViewController setGoal:100];
  }
}
```

Comment: cheers for your help @Fillip -  though i've tried above and get the following - 'property 'destviewcontroller' not found on object of type uistoryboardsegue *; did you mean 'source view controller'

Comment: cheers Filip - switched that but unfortunately it now errors with - no visible @ instance method for editViewController declares the selector setGoal..  frustrating!  It is setup as a method in the .M file - do i need to add a declaration to the modal.h file!?

Comment: Yes, all the methods that you call outside of the "modal" should be in the .h file to be accesable

Comment: cool added as -(void)setGoal:(NSString*)setGoal; and all is cool - cheers for your help!